# Total for dynamic columns

Tags: java, excel, jxls

I have a report with 1 dynamic column. I've written the second each that extends in RIGHT direction and this works well.

However, I have an issue when I want to count totals for every such columns.
I thought that I can write a SUM(B2) formula and extend it RIGHT, but it doesn't work.

Even without third loop, formula transforms to SUM(B2:xY), so it counts SUM of entire dynamic area.

Ofc, I can write some java code to count total or make another query,but it there any way to do this without programming?

Thanks.

Here is simplified template layout. I want to count SUM of every dynamic column, so if there are x rows and y dynamic columns I need SUM(B2:Bx), SUM(C2:Cx) ... SUM(y2:yx)

[image: sample]